# Searching html element properties

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to grab information from my company's booking engine to use in an Excel document. I am having trouble searching the HTML.

I am trying to check if it is on the login page or if it is already logged in. Since the login page has big header which says 'Login' I search to see if the page had a header with the innerText property 'Login' and if so input the details to log in.

I get

> Run-time error (438)
> 'object doesn't support this method or property'.

```vb
Sub Bookings()

Dim HTLMDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Dim url As String
Dim email As Object
Dim pwd As Object

Dim header As Object

Dim username As String
Dim password As String

username = "companyemail"
password = "companypassword"

url = "urlOfOurBookingEngine"
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Silent = True
ie.navigate url
ie.Visible = True

Do

Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTLMDoc = ie.document

Set header = HTLMDoc.getElementsByTagName("H1")

If header.innerText = "Login" Then

    Set email = HTLMDoc.getElementById("username")
    Set pwd = HTLMDoc.getElementById("password")

    email.Value = username
    pwd.Value = password
    SendKeys "~"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set header = HTLMDoc.getElementsByTagName("H1")(0)` not `Set header = HTLMDoc.getElementsByTagName("H1")`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your runtime error is your attempt to return the value for an object's property that doesn't exist when you run the following lines:

```
Set header = HTLMDoc.getElementsByTagName("H1")

If header.innerText = "Login" Then
```

Here's a quick walkthrough this error. When you instantiate the "header" Object using your Set statement, your code creates this object by calling the "getElementsByTagName" method on your "HTLMDoc" object.

When you call this method, it uses your parameter (the html tag as a string) and returns a **IHTMLElementCollection**.

The problem? **innerText** is not a property of an IHTMLElementCollection. So, when you attempt to return the data value for the innerText property for header,

```
If header.innerText = "Login" Then
```

you get your runtime error - because that property doesn't exist.

**The fix:** simply append another method to your Set statement. Here is an example...

[image]

As you can see in this image, I appended the **item** method, which takes your IHTMLElementCollection and returns a specified object as a **HTMLHeaderElement** in our case. I used Facebook's login page for my example and so the innerText of header in my example is "Facebook".

Note: The **item** method has parameters you can pass to specify the object in your collection that you want to return - I didn't include them because in my case, my collection had only one object. If you're interested, here's the documentation on the **item** method, including its parameters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh870051(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Just to confirm, I ran your whole sub procedure after adding this fix. And I used Facebook's login page and it worked. Here is the updated script and a snapshot of the webpage after running it:

```
Sub Bookings()

Dim HTLMDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Dim url As String
Dim email As Object
Dim pwd As Object

Dim header As Object

Dim username As String
Dim password As String

username = "companyemail"
password = "companypassword"

url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Silent = True
ie.navigate url
ie.Visible = True

Do

Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTLMDoc = ie.document

Set header = HTLMDoc.getElementsByTagName("h1").Item

If header.innerText = "Facebook" Then
    Set email = HTLMDoc.getElementById("m_login_email")
    Set pwd = HTLMDoc.getElementById("m_login_password")

    email.Value = username
    pwd.Value = password
    
    SendKeys "~"

End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions / other issues!